# Piecewise function plots weird when given expression with symbol vs writing it explicitly

Tags: plotting, piecewise

The only difference is that in the second snippet the expression is written out explicitly.

```
displacement = (Sin[x - Pi/2 - t] + 1)/2
```

This doesn't work:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[
  {
   Piecewise[{{displacement, t <= x <= t + 2 Pi}}, 0]
   },
  {x, 0, 20},
  PlotRange -> All
  ],
 {t, 0, 20}
 ]
```

[image]

but this works:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[
  {
   Piecewise[{{(Sin[x - Pi/2 - t] + 1)/2, t <= x <= t + 2 Pi}}, 0]
   },
  {x, 0, 20},
  PlotRange -> All
  ],
 {t, 0, 20}
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Add `Evaluated -> True` to the `Plot[]` and try again.

Comment: @J.M. Doesn't work.

Comment: Ah, I see what's happening: try looking at the result of `Manipulate[Table[displacement, {x, 0, 2}], {t, 0, 20}]`.

Comment: @J.M. Yeah it outputs {1/2 (1 - Cos[t]), 1/2 (1 - Cos[1 - t]), 1/2 (1 - Cos[2 - t])} and the "t"s aren't changing.

Comment: So, you now understand what happened to your original example?

Comment: @J.M. I don't. What is the difference between writing the expression explicitly and assigning the value to a symbol and using that?

Comment: You saw what happened with `Table[]`. That is what's happening to `Plot[]` too, which of course cannot plot anything with a dangling symbol.

Comment: @J.M. Finally I get it. This works. `Manipulate[
 Plot[
  {
   Piecewise[{{(displacement /. t -> time), 
      time <= x <= time + 2 Pi}}, 0]
   },
  {x, 0, 20},
  PlotRange -> All,
  Evaluated -> True
  ],
 {time, 0, 20}
 ]`  Have I understood correctly that the Manipulate function replaces all occurrences of t before evaluating the Piecewise. So because it doesn't contain t before evaluation it is left dangling.

Comment: More or less, yes. :) Consider writing an answer to your own question.